# convexity of function having set domain

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

Suppose we have a finite set $G \subset \mathbb{R}$. And it has $n$ elements. $|G| = n$

And we have a function $f: P(G) \to \mathbb{R}$, where $P(G)$ is the powerset of $G$.

I'm wondering how can I approach the proof of convexity or not to this function $f$?

For a real function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, i can check the second derivative is positive.

Also if it helps, the explicit form of my function is $f(S):= u(S)-l(S)$.

Here $u$ is the sum of the upper half of $S$, and $l$ is the sum of the lower half of $S$.

If $S$ has an odd number of elements, its median is skipped.

To reuse the standard definition of convexity, I can use $\{0, 1\}^n$ vectors as input domain, and apply some sophisticated operation to achieve the same output $f': \{0, 1\}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. would this $f'$ be convex?

Comment: What is your definition of convexity for a function of this kind?

Comment: hmm.. still trying to bend my head around this, need to find a proper way to embed input and fix the input dimension. One thing i can think of is to use a binary vector $\{0, 1\}^n$ as input of the function and apply some kind of sorting inside of the function to achieve same output. would the function then be convex with respect to binary vectors?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add comments, but feel free to move this to a comment or delete it if it is not useful. Why don't you define convexity using
Minkowski sums?. Then you can say $f$ is convex if
$$f(\theta X\oplus (1-\theta)Y)\leq \theta f(X)+(1-\theta)f(Y)$$
holds for all $X,Y\in P(G)$ and all $\theta\in[0,1]$. Strict convexity could be defined for the above relation with strict inequality and $\theta\in(0,1)$ and all $X\neq Y$. Here, $\oplus$ is the Minkowski sum
$X\oplus Y = \{ x+y | x\in X, y\in Y\}$. Then you could use the usual convexity machinery just adapted for Minkowski sums.